# Remove entry in KDB column table with regex matching?

Tags: kdb

How can i remove a row in a KDB table matching a certain regex?

For example:

**Initial Table**

```
index | value  | number
  0   |  a_fo  |  999
  1   |  b_fo  |  999
  2   |  c_fo  |  999
  3   |  c_ba  |  999
```

The query should remove all entries in the `value` column that matches the regex `c_*`, where the value starts with `c_` and any length of characters afterwards.

**Resultant Table**

```
index | value  | number
  0   |  a_fo  |  999
  1   |  b_fo  |  999
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively you can index in to avoid using the delete template for something a bit quicker

```
t where not t[`value] like "c*"
```

Or else use a functional delete

```
![t;enlist(like;`value;"c_*");0b;`$()]
```

Regarding naming the column value which is a reserved keyword in q you can use .Q.id which will rename badly named variables to avoid any issues for example :

```
.Q.id t
results in the columns `index`value1`number
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I wouldn't name the column as value. This will lead to errors.

```
index val  number
-----------------
0     a_fo 999
1     b_fo 999
2     c_fo 999
3     c_ba 999
```

Using delete should do i

```
t:delete from t where val like "c_*"
```

You need to redefine t if you want the table to update.

Comment: Alternative to re-assigning to `t` is to use `\`t` in the query to make the delete occur "in place" i.e. `delete from \`t where val like "c_*"`. Probably also worth noting that `value` is a keyword in kdb & this is the reason it can cause issues as a column name